# how to get process infos running on a vm from host machine

Tags: virtual-machine, libvirt

I want get info about a process inside a virtual machine from the host machine,
is there any methods in libvirt to implement this? any help is appreciated!

Comment: does it have to be through libvirt?  or can you ssh in and run ps?

Comment: ssh in and run ps is practicable,but in my case,there are lot of vms,so it's not convenient to ssh in every vm and run ps cmd.